# Emulating webkit in IE (whatever possible)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, webkit, emulation

I am literally sick of it. I have an advanced web application relies on lots of Javascript libraries (jQuery, jQueryUI, OpenLayers, highcharts, EJSChart and many more). Needless to say Internet Explorer is a huge pain for web developers. Everything works like charm in every other browser except IE. Each time I work on a new feature I have to spend ridiculous amount of time to get IE working. It is like a nightmare, I hate it so much.

Good thing, I have managed the users switch to Firefox or Chrome. Well mostly. There is only %4 left stuck in IE, but I don't feel like I care about them.

Is there any kind of an emulator for IE to act like a Webkit browser? I don't care if it relies on weird technologies or add-ons.

Comment: Google Chrome Frame of course! http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/

Comment: It must be tinnitus. / Runs off.

Comment: @Bryan: why didn't you put that as an answer? Seems strange to put an answer in the comments...

Comment: Perhaps you should consider a new career or focus.

Comment: I didn't have time to put together a full answer and I assumed this question was likely a duplicate. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome Frame is the answer: http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/

From the site:

> Google Chrome Frame is an open source plug-in that seamlessly brings Google Chrome's open web technologies and speedy JavaScript engine to Internet Explorer.

Comment: No the end user has to install Chrome Frame.

Answer (score 3):

This project attempts to do that: http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't improve speed, but it this is handy.

Answer (score 0):

You can whine about IE, or get a used bucket of bolts and run IE on it until you can make it work. However you measure it, more  people use IE than everything else. A world that only allowed new luxury cars to drive on the roads might be easier to deal with, but all kinds of jalopies travel the information highway.